# Ruby Terminology Question: Is this a Ruby declaration, definition and assignment, all at the same time?

Tags: ruby, terminology, declaration, definition

If I say:

x = "abc"

this seems like a declaration, definition and assignment, all at the same time, regardless of whether I have said anything about x in the program before.

Is this correct?

I'm not sure what the correct terminology is in Ruby for declarations, definitions and assigments or if there is even a distinction between these things because of the dynamic typing in Ruby.

@tg: Regarding your point # 2: even if x existed before the x = "abc" statement, couldn't you call the x = "abc" statement a definition/re-definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Declaration:** *No.*
   It doesn't make sense to talk about **declaring** variables in Ruby, because there's nothing analogous to a declaration in the languages.  Languages designed for compilers have declarations because the compiler needs to know in advance how big datatypes are and how to access different parts of them.  *e.g.*, if I say in C:

   ```
   int *i;
   ```

   then the compiler knows that somewhere there is some memory set aside for i, and it's as big as it needs to be to hold a pointer to an int.  Eventually the linker will hook all the references to `i` together, but at least the compiler knows it's out there somewhere.
2. **Definition:** *Probably*.
   A **definition** typically set an initial value for something (at least in the familiar compiled languages).  If `x` didn't exist before the `x = "abc"` statement, then I guess you could call this a definition, since that is when Ruby has to assign a value to the symbol `x`.

   Again, though, *definition* is a specific term that people typically use to distinguish the initial, static assignment of a value to some variable from that variable's declaration.  In Ruby, you don't have that kind of statement.  You typically just say a variable is *defined* if it's been assigned a value somewhere in your current scope, and you say it's *undefined* if it hasn't.

   You usually don't talk about it having a *definition*, because in Ruby that just amounts to *assignment*.  There's no special context that would justify you saying *definition* like there is in other languages.

   Which brings us to...
3. **Assignment:** *Yes.*
   You can definitely call this an **assignment**, since it is assigning a value to the symbol `x`.  I don't think anyone will disagree with that.

Comment: @tg: Regarding your point # 2: even if x existed before the x = "abc" statement, couldn't you call that statement a definition/re-definition?

Comment: @in bruges: you could, and you might be semantically sound, but I think at that point it starts sounding a little awkward b/c it's a specific term that doesn't directly apply to ruby.  People usually just say "reassign".  I tried to clarify this above.

Comment: One could argue that it is also a declaration, since it resolves the method/variable ambiguity in favor of a variable till the end of the source file. See "Variable/Method Ambiguity" in http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/language.html .

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much. And if, on the very next line, you do:

```
x = 1
```

Then you've just *re-defined* it, as well as assigned it (its now an integer, not a string). Duck typing is very different to what you're probably used to.